# android:id="@+id/user_info" is null

Tags: android, butterknife

I can run my application with an account. But account info seems like null on profile page. and so the app crash because of null value. I searched that there was a bug with butterknife. I am new to android. please help me to solve this problem. first I had an error NPE and I saw that id is null.

**my fragment_account.xml is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_face"
            android:padding="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cirlce"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Üye No: 18598575"
            android:textColor="@color/profile_uye_no_color"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title_sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#565656"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/big_sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_name"
            tools:text="AppLogist Bilisim Teknolojileri San. ve Tic. Limited Sirketi" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/profile_edit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_gradiant_blue"
            android:text="@string/account_edit_profile_button_text"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/provizyon_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.2dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_color" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/next_3_kopya_2"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/next_3_kopya_2"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito"
                android:text="@string/account_provizyon_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/medium_sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.2dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_color" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/satin_alma_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.2dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_color" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/next_3_kopya_2"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/next_3_kopya_2"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito"
                android:text="@string/account_buyings"
                android:textSize="@dimen/medium_sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.2dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_color" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ihale_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito"
                android:textSize="@dimen/medium_sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/next_3_kopya_2"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/next_3_kopya_2"
                android:text="@string/account_offers_text" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.2dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_color" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cikis_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/account_exit_text"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito"
                android:textSize="@dimen/medium_sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/next_3_kopya_2"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/next_3_kopya_2"
                android:textColor="@color/orange_color" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.2dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_color" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**my AccountFragment.java is:**

```
 @BindView(R.id.user_info)
    protected TextView userInfo;
```

**my logcat is:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.applogist.filomotive.network.responese.model.user.UserModel com.applogist.filomotive.network.responese.model.login.LoginModel.getUserInfo()' on a null object reference
```

[my profil page with "üye no..."Normally the first and last name should appear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joaj3.png)

**my LoginModel.java is:**

```
public class LoginModel extends BaseModel {

    @SerializedName("LoginKey")
    private String loginKey;

    @SerializedName("LogoutTime")
    private Date logoutTime;

    @SerializedName("UserInfo")
    private UserModel userInfo;


    public String getLoginKey() {
        return loginKey;
    }

    public void setLoginKey(String loginKey) {
        this.loginKey = loginKey;
    }

    public Date getLogoutTime() {
        return logoutTime;
    }

    public void setLogoutTime(Date logoutTime) {
        this.logoutTime = logoutTime;
    }

    public UserModel getUserInfo() {
        return userInfo;
    }

    public void setUserInfo(UserModel userInfo) {
        this.userInfo = userInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LoginModel{" +
                "loginKey='" + loginKey + '\'' +
                ", logoutTime=" + logoutTime +
                ", userInfo=" + userInfo +
                '}';
    }
}
```

my model cannot receive userInfo.

Comment: use view binding or data binding

Comment: can you give some more information Rohit? I think that I use view binding.

Comment: This isn't helping, add the error in the question too and also give some more context of the problem.

Comment: and stop using butterknife as it is deprecated. Use View Binding.

Comment: I have edited my question above. please help me if you can.

Comment: tycoon, i thought i was using viewbinding but when i show the info which is in fragment_account.xml on line android:id="@+id/profile_image" it include that "Supply an identifier name for this view, to later retrieve it with {@link android.view.View#findViewById View.findViewById()} or {@link android.app.Activity#findViewById Activity.findViewById()}. This must be a resource reference; typically you set this using the @+ syntax to create a new ID resources. For example: android:id="@+id/my_id" which allows you to later retrieve the view with findViewById(R.id.my_id)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private UserModel userInfo = new UserModel();
```

in LoginModel.java object creation is required as above. sorry for my poor info about this question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't bind view in fragment or missing implementation in gradle. Try it:

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {
 
    private Unbinder unbinder;
 
    @BindView(R.id.user_info)
    protected TextView mTvUserInfo;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_account, container, false);
 
        // bind view using butter knife
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
 
        return view;
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
 
        // unbind the view to free some memory
        unbinder.unbind();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
If it's problem in Gradle, you can add below line in your `app:Build-Gradle`:

```
android {
  ...
  // Butterknife requires Java 8.
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
}
```

Comment: I did. But it doesnt work. same scenario the I have. what am I missing implementation in gradle?

Comment: It does't help me but thank you Silver. I have edited my question above.